Firewall rule against firebase function. Specifically firebase onRequest v1
My onRequest cloud functions are currently getting spammed by requests from an ip address 163.172.220.11.  I have set up my own custom rate limiting that tracks requests per hour for specific ip addresses.  This works fine, but it doesn't prevent someone from just sending over a million requests regardless of the 429 or 403 that gets sent back.  Is there a way to black list this IP from being able to even invoke my function? It seems there isn't much else I can do.

Have you reviewed App Engine Firewall?

would i need to move my functions into there?

Like samthecodingman suggested....
I ended up creating an express server and deployed it to app engine instead of within firebase functions.  From there, I could set up firewall rules to explicitly block specific Ip Addresses.  It would be nice if firebase would add some kind of security features like this, but for now app engine will have to do.
